# How to monitor a container running db2 image using Prometheus and also react app using Prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, monitoring, prometheus, react-fullstack

I have to build a monitoring solution using Prometheus and Graphana for a service which is built using React(front end)+ Node js + Db2(containerised) . I have no idea where to start,can someone suggest me the resources where to learn?Thank you.

Comment: did you try to go through the installation manual for Prometheus and Grafana?

Comment: Yes,from my understaning we need to install clients on containers which will provide metrics for prometheus server,but I don't want to change anything from application code (because that is written by someone else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to install Prometheus and Grafana in your Kubernetes cluster following the instructions given for each:

Prometheus: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/

Grafana: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/

Next, you need to understand that Prometheus is a pull-based metrics collection system. It retrieves metrics from configured targets (endpoints) at given intervals and displays the results.

You can setup the working monitoring system by implementing the below steps:

1. Instrument your application code for Prometheus to be able to scrape metric from -
   For this, you need to add instrumentation to the code via one of the supported [Prometheus client libraries](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/).
2. Configure Prometheus to scrape the metrics exposed by the service - Prometheus supports a K8s custom resource named `ServiceMonitor` introduced by the [Prometheus Operator](https://coreos.com/blog/the-prometheus-operator.html) that can be used to configure Prometheus to scrape the metric defined in step 1.
3. Observe the scraped metrics - Next, you can observe the defined metric in either the Prometheus UI or Grafana UI by [configuring Grafana support for Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/).